# page heading for bibliography showing previous chapter

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, memoir

the following MWE shows the

- memoir class with
- headstyles "dowding"

printing the

- chapter name on the right of the head of a verso page and
- section name on the left of the head of the recto.

Then we go to the backmatter and use printbibheading and printbibliography (my document has many sections of bibliography) this

- gives the right entry in the toc
- puts the bib section name on the left of the head of the recto page but
- (PROBLEM HERE) still places the previous chapter name on the right of the verso. I'd like the bibliography name here.

I thank you for any suggestions.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@book{ICoS,
    Isbn = {978-92-801-4198-6},Publisher = {International Maritime Organization},
    Title = {International Code of Signals},Date = {2005},Label = {IMO05}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
%------------------Style-------------------------
\chapterstyle{dowding}
\headstyles{dowding}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{chapter name}
\section{section name}
\lipsum[1-10]
\cite{ICoS}
\backmatter
\printbibheading[%
heading=bibintoc, % bibintoc adds the Bibliography to the table of contents
title={bibliography name} % If we want to override the default title "Bibliography" 
]
%\lipsum[1-10]
\printbibliography[title={books},heading=subbibintoc]
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I get the expected result. Which `biblatex` versio are you using?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I get the OP's described results with an up to date TeXLive 2017 (that is, biblatex 3.9).

Comment: Why don't you use `\chapter{blbiography name}` instead of `\printbibheading...`? It should produce the same output, and as far as headings are concerned (and as far as I've tested), should do what you want.

Comment: @g Ah right, i didn't update to 3.9 yet. I remember that there was an update concerning headers. All the times people complained that `biblatex` sets the mark, now that this is changed, people ask for the contrary.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I see, I was unaware of this "dispute". In my tests here `\printbibliography` does set the (left) mark "books". But `\printbibheading` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if it were a feature or a bug :)
The printbibheading is quite useful for me.
How do I set the mark manually?

Comment: `\markright` and `\markboth` would be the manual commands. But why exactly is `\printbibheading` useful to you in this scenario? If we understand it better, there might be a more general way to deal with it.

Comment: @gusbrs I guess something like this, but the screenshot doesn t seem to match the code? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#Separate_Bibliographies_by_Entry_Type

Comment: @Johannes_B, it may well be, but this could be achieved with `chapter` instead of `printbibheading` (that's the missing line of code there...). Anyway, I did some more tests. In the book class the marks are set for both chapter and section level, and for both `printbibheading` and `printbibliography`. But with `memoir` the chapter level is not set with `printbibheading` and neither with `printbibliography`, whereas it is set at the section level with either command. I don't see how that's a "feature".

Comment: Hi, I had confused myself!
\chapter{blbiography name} works fine for me. Sorry! (I had thought that this would cause the bib to be numbered (like my appendicees) but the \backmatter supresses it.

Johannes_B has guessed the context - I use biblatex to cite and reference a lot, not just make a bibliography, so I use various filters and structure. 

Thankyou all, I will go with this simplest solution!

Comment: We will have a look at that in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/627 again. Please feel free to join the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `\chapter{bibliography name}` instead of `printbibheading...`. Like:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@book{ICoS,
    Isbn = {978-92-801-4198-6},Publisher = {International Maritime Organization},
    Title = {International Code of Signals},Date = {2005},Label = {IMO05}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
%------------------Style-------------------------
\chapterstyle{dowding}
\headstyles{dowding}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{chapter name}
\section{section name}
\lipsum[1-10]
\cite{ICoS}
\backmatter
\chapter{bibliography name}
%\lipsum[1-10]
\printbibliography[title={books},heading=subbibintoc]
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still, this behavior begs the question. Perhaps someone more acquainted with `biblatex`+`memoir` can shed some further light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue so I simply did this.

```
\rhead{\textit{}}
\lhead{\textit{}}
```

I left them empty on the chapter of biblography. Actually when you set the format of your document so the format follows for all the pages, now for example if you are mentioning headers of other chapters and if don't do it for bibliography so it will inherit the header of the last chapter. So if you want some certain elements not to be followed on some chapter simply leave them null.